# For which c, d is Gap2SAT[c, d] in P (such that 0<c<d<1)?

Tags: complexity-theory, 2-sat

For which $c, d$ is $Gap2SAT[c, d]$ in $P$  (such that $0<c<d<1$)?

(I know if d=1 then for each c it will be in P, however with which c,d such that  $0<c<d<1$ can I simply return YES?)

Comment: What is Gap2SAT?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Unique Games Conjecture, your problem is solved for MAX-CUT in Ryan O'Donnell and Yi Wu, [An optimal SDP algorithm for Max-Cut,
and equally optimal Long Code tests](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/optimal-max-cut.pdf), who determined the *gap curve* for this problem.

I am not aware of any such work for MAX-2SAT, but Per Austrin has essentially determined the optimal approximation ratio (again, assuming the Unique Games Conjecture) in his paper [Balanced MAX 2-SAT might not be the hardest](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.634.5706&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

In celebrated work, [Prasad Raghavendra](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~prasad/Files/thesis.pdf) has essentially determined the optimal approximation ratio for *any* constraint-satisfaction problem, again assuming the Unique Games Conjecture.